# GSON: END_OBJECT never get called

Tags: android, json, gson, jsonreader

I have a JSON like:

> {"aData":
>
> > {"tournaments":
> >
> > > {"new":[
> > >
> > > > {"token":"1-token", "prio":"6", "status":"inactive", ..., "_timeCreated":"2014-04-14 14:44:49", "_timeChanged":"2014-08-08 12:30:20"},
> > > >
> > > > {"token":"2-token","prio":"8","status":"inactive",...}
> > >
> > > ] }
> >
> > }
>
> }

the JSON file is 8 MB big and is valid, as it can be parsed with default `new JSONObject(str)` or within a `Volley's JsonObjectRequest`.

The code I use:

```
 reader = new JsonReader( new InputStreamReader( am.open( "updatedata.json" ) ) );
 reader.setLenient( true );
 while( reader.hasNext() ){
   eachToken( reader );
   Log.i( TAG, "has next " + reader.hasNext() );
 }

private boolean eachToken( JsonReader reader ) throws IOException {
  JsonToken token = reader.peek();
  switch( token ){
    case BEGIN_ARRAY:
      reader.beginArray();
      Log.i( TAG, "array <<" );
      break;
    case END_ARRAY:
      reader.endArray();
      Log.i( TAG, "array >>" );
      break;
    case BEGIN_OBJECT:
      reader.beginObject();
      Log.i( TAG, "{" );
      break;
    case END_OBJECT:
      reader.endObject();
      Log.i( TAG, "}" );
      break;
    case NAME:
      String name = reader.nextName();
      Log.i( TAG, name );
      break;
    case STRING:
      String s = reader.nextString();
      Log.i( TAG, s );
      break;
    case NUMBER:
      int n = reader.nextInt();
      Log.i( TAG, "" + n );
      break;
    case BOOLEAN:
      boolean b = reader.nextBoolean();
      Log.i( TAG, "" + b );
      break;
    case NULL:
      reader.nextNull();
      Log.i( TAG, "null" );
      break;
    case END_DOCUMENT:
      Log.i( TAG, "end doc" );
      return false;
    default:
      Log.i( TAG, token.toString() );
  }
  return true;
}
```

the problem is, that the case `END_OBJECT` is never reached. It prints the following into the `logcat`:

```
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): {
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): aData
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): {
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): tournaments
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): {
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): new
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): array <<
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): {
  01-06 13:30:32.817: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): token
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): 1-token
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): prio
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): 6
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): status
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.827: I/DataService(1819): inactive
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): _timeCreated
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): 2014-04-14 14:44:49
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): _timeChanged
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): has next true
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): 2014-08-08 12:30:20
  01-06 13:30:32.837: I/DataService(1819): has next false
```

so, it reaches the `"_timeChanged":"2014-08-08 12:30:20"` of the 1st object, and then `reader.hasNext()` turns `false` instead of moving to the new `BEGIN_OBJECT` token.

what am I missing? TIA

Comment: I have had problems with GSON recognising (non-json) arrays within json, that is square bracket arrays. I found that I have to create a class for the json api response that included MyClass[] array classes. Could this be the issue?

Comment: why `[]` arrays are non-json?

Comment: There is an alternative way of structuring array data in json that I have seen used in some projects that doesn't use square brackets. I always called this a json array and square brackets arrays I just called arrays. It looks like it may only be me who makes this distinction. In attempting to make my answer clearer, I made it less clear, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

`hasNext()` says "Returns true if the current array or object has another element." In your case, when it hits the end of an object or array `hasNext()` is `false` so `case END_ARRAY` and `case END_OBJECT` don't get called.

This may work:

```
while( reader.hasNext() 
        || reader.peek() == END_ARRAY 
        || reader.peek() == END_OBJECT ){
    eachToken( reader );
    Log.i( TAG, "has next " + reader.hasNext() );
}
```

This is essentially the same as Joey's answer but wouldn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue might be in the way you handle the Data

If you look at the [JavaDoc](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) for `JsonReader` it especially defines that you need to consume array brackets ..

> Within array handling methods, first call beginArray() to consume the array's opening bracket. Then create a while loop that accumulates values, terminating when hasNext() is false. Finally, read the array's closing bracket by calling endArray().

So `hasNext()` is false after the array is finished ...

Comment: hmmm, I'm getting `hasNext() == false` already at the end of the 1st element of the array, way before the array finishes...